# How to remove parameters from a URL on an ASP.NET site that uses URL Routing?

Tags: asp.net, parameters, url-routing, query-string

I recently added **URL Routing** to my **non-MVC site** that's based on ASP.NET and C#.  So now if I get the following incoming request:

```
http://www.coolsite.com/item/27
```

...I can remap this behind the scenes to:

```
http://www.coolsite.com/widgets.aspx?id=27
```

Today, I added an additional parameter to the end of the URL to track the User who "Liked" this link on Facebook.  I want to build a **referral or flower type graph** so I can track which users shared or liked something, and which of their friends followed the shared link.  So, for user "Joe" who has an ID of 333, the URL looks like this if he "Likes" the page:

```
http://www.coolsite.com/item/27/333
```

The value "333" is important to me only when the page is being built on the server so I can update my FacebookLikeReferral DB table, but I don't really want (or need) to show the "333" parameter in the address box after the page has loaded.

What's the best practice way to **modify the URL** (via Routing or some other mechanism) **to remove the "333"** or **"/333"** from the end of the URL?

Comment: how you solved this problem  ??

Answer (score 0):

Return a Redirect result without that parameter.

Comment: Isn't this potentially expensive if I'm doing it with every request?  Also, would Server.Transfer be a better option compared to Response.Redirect?

Comment: Server.Transfer won't change the URL in the browser. If you really need to change the URL in the browser Response.Redirect is the only sensible option. If you do this every request this will be expensive.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. My hope was there there would be a .NET-specific way to do this as part of the URL Routing framework.  The cleanup that I'm looking for is purely cosmetic, so I'm not prepared to take an expensive perf hit to make a pretty URL.